# Receiving Mongo error when trying to start up mongo instance for Rocket.Chat

Tags: mongodb, rocket.chat

I restarted the server that holds a private Rocket.Chat server, and I suddenly started seeing the following issue with the mongo instance that starts with RC:

```
[initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=12518 port=27017 dbpath=/var/snap/rocketchat-server/common 64-bit host=fight_club_wi
[initandlisten] db version v3.4.20
[initandlisten] git version: 447847d93d6e0a21b018d5df45528e815c7c13d8
[initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
[initandlisten] modules: none
[initandlisten] build environment:
[initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
[initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
[initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, processManagement: { pidFilePath: "/var/snap/rocketchat-server/common/mongod.pid" }, replication: { replSet: "rs0" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/snap/rocketchat-server/common", journal: { enabled: true }, mmapv1: { smallFiles: true } } }
[initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/snap/rocketchat-server/common created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
[initandlisten]
[initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
[initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
[initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3471M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
[initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1589320129:556327][12518:0x7f7a2e9d8d00], txn-recover: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build  only supports major/minor versions up to 1/0,  and the file is version 2/0: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
[initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1589320129:556377][12518:0x7f7a2e9d8d00], txn-recover: WiredTiger is unable to read the recovery log.
[initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1589320129:556395][12518:0x7f7a2e9d8d00], txn-recover: This may be due to the log files being encrypted, being from an older version or due to corruption on disk
[initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1589320129:556409][12518:0x7f7a2e9d8d00], txn-recover: You should confirm that you have opened the database with the correct options including all encryption and compression options
[initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1589320129:556427][12518:0x7f7a2e9d8d00], txn-recover: Recovery failed: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
[initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:-31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 277
[initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 -31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error, terminating
[initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
[initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
[initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
[initandlisten] now exiting
[initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

I am not sure what has caused the issue other than possibly a recent update to mongo, but I don't believe that has happened as I am not seeing any logs over the past twelve hours that would suggest an update.

I am currently running the latest stable Rocket Chat version on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server. Nginx just returns a 502 Bad Gateway error but I believe that is a red herring because the DB will not load, and when I query the website that the machine holds and the Nginx server directs to that works just fine.

Am I going to need to start fresh because of this?

Any suggested help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, I have no idea what happened. I was preparing to follow Max's suggestion, but before I did I wanted to clone the drive for backup. After cloning the drive, I stuck the backup in the original machine to make sure it would boot properly, and 'lo and behold the db is now loading properly. I am a little speechless, but I wanted to thank everyone for their input.

Answer (score 0):

This error:

> WiredTiger error (-31802) [1589320129:556327][12518:0x7f7a2e9d8d00], txn-recover: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build  only supports major/minor versions up to 1/0,  and the file is version 2/0: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error

Indicates that the data files were written by a newer version of MongoDB.

You can either upgrade to MongoDB 4.0 in order to read the existing files, or clear the files from the data directory and start fresh.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the .lock file in the data/db folder and try again